# Pivot table output name and ModelBuilder failing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase, error-000229

I have created a model that utilises the Pivot Table tool. When I run the model, the tool creates a DBF file in a file GDB. However the naming convention of the file is incorrect. It just has the name "dbf", rather than the output table name stated in the parameters. It subsequently stops the model from continuing giving me an error:

> ERROR 000229: Cannot open
>   C:\AIS\Model_testing_area\AIS_2013_Density.gdb\PivotTable.dbf Failed
>   to execute (Add Join). I have tried to trim the name, change the
>   workspaces (in_memory, %currentworkspace%) however to no avail.

[image: Model]

[image: Pivot Table Parameters]

[image: GDB file]

Comment: You cannot have a file extension ".dbf" within a geodatabase.  Try removing the extension part and re-run the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot save a table in a geodatabase with an extension like ".dbf".  Remove the extension and the tool should run.